# understanding the pointer returned by strtok

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I have this code, where I tokenize a string and search for a value.

```
char string[]="Name=Marcus&greeting=goodmorning";
char* Name=parsePostData("Name",string);




char* parsePostData(char s[],char t[])
{
  char *pch;
  char *pp="Marcus";

  char tCpy[512];//Make a copy. Otherwise, strtok works on the char pointer, and original char array gets modified/ corrupted.
  strcpy(tCpy,t);
  pch = strtok (tCpy,"=&");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
      if(strcmp(pch,s)==0) {
            pch= strtok (NULL, "&"); 
            //Case 1. what I need. but it is causing issues 
            //after I write to flash, and restart the board.
            return pch;   

            //Case 2. Forced test case. works perfect.             
            //return pp;


      }else{
        pch = strtok (NULL, "=&");  
      }
  }

}
```

what is the difference between the two cases inside the function?

Comment: `char l[]` has automatic storage duration. When the function returns, `l`'s lifetime ends, and any access to it is undefined behaviour. You need to `malloc()` storage for your string if you want to return it.

Comment: @EOF I updated the question to show my real problem. Could you please take a look? I am working on an arduino board, and using dueFlashStorage library to write values to flash. But this function is giving me trouble for two days now.

Comment: You're still returning a pointer into an array with automatic storage duration. Before returning in case 1, `char *retval = malloc(strlen(pch)+1); strcpy(retval, pch); /*or shorter: strdup() if available*/ return retval;`.

Comment: char *pch has automatic storage duration. When the function returns, pch's lifetime ends, and any access to it is undefined behaviour. You need to malloc() storage for your string if you want to return it.

Comment: @EOF you're trying your best, I know :)

Comment: @MartinJames: Cute, but actually it's `char tCpy[]` that has automatic storage duration.

Comment: @EOF I tried strdup(). It still gives problem. Problem being, case 1: If I write the returned value to arduino flash memory, and reset the board, it shows junk values. Case 2: No problem at all.

Comment: @aVC: Would you mind posting your current code?

Comment: @EOF https://ideone.com/Zthm5x Please note that this is code for arduino board, and I am using this library: https://github.com/sebnil/DueFlashStorage

Comment: @aVC: Your `struct Configuration` contains `char *`s. You need to serialize the data before writing it to flash. Currently you're writing *the pointer*.

Comment: @EOF I dont think that is causing the issue. for one, I tried removing that member from struct. Problem persists. Second, in my Case 2, everything works fine. Third, the example is from the library author. If I run it as is, it works without any issues too. It is just the strtok that causes the issue. (seems like)

Comment: This looks like a single threaded embedded event loop. The embedded environment might be cleaning up your heap for you each time you exit your loop. Can you try changing the type of `tCpy` to `static` instead, and `return pch;` (no `strdup`)?

Comment: @EOF I tried making tCpy static, letting the function consume the string, etc as John suggested below. Still shows the issue.

Comment: @aVC, do not discount EOF's advice so quickly.  He is exactly right: you are writing pointers (addresses) into flash, *not the strings they point to*.  Your problem *cannot* have persisted when you removed the pointers from your struct, because your problem involves data loss when try to store those very pointers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger May be I misunderstood. I thought he was talking about the member "char c", which I was not using. But if he meant char* member, then I am doing the same thing as the original code does, except instead of writing an arbitrary string, I bring it from a function. thats why I thought it may not have been the issue.

Comment: @aVC, EOF was talking about the pointers, exactly as he said.  Those would be `Configuration.message` and `Configuration.m2`.  If you want to save the message text that those point to to flash, then the way you are attempting to do it is plain wrong.  I don't care if something similar worked -- or seemed to do -- in a related program.

Comment: @aVC, but if there is a fixed upper bound on the lengths of those messages, then you could solve the problem by declaring them as arrays instead of pointers (e.g. `char message[50];`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can set an upperbound, but I wanted to start with the library example as it is and see if works for me. May be upperbound is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference between the two cases inside the function?

## Case 1.

As several people have now told you, the sequence

```
pch = strtok (tCpy,"=&");
/* ... */
pch= strtok (NULL, "&");
```

results in `pch` being a pointer into local array `tCpy` (or NULL, if the original string did not contain either '=' or '&').  Because `tCpy` is a *local* array, it goes out of scope at the end of the function, at which point any pointers into it cease to be valid.  In practice, the memory it occupied probably gets reused by the next function called.

---

## Case 2.

The code

```
char *pp="Marcus";
```

initializes `pp` to point at a static, anonymous character array whose contents are the null-terminated string `"Marcus"`.  Because the array has static storage duration, a pointer to it remains valid after the function exits.

---

You have three main options for working around this issue:

1. The caller provides the function pre-allocated storage for the string copy.  That could be a work array (not necessarily dynamically allocated), or it could take the form of just letting the function consume the string, with the *caller* being responsible for making a copy if necessary.
2. The function allocates storage for the copy dynamically.  There are a lot of ways that could go, but the `strdup()` function is a quick and easy way to allocate and copy in one step.
3. You could make array `tCpy` static.  Then pointers into it would remain valid after return from the function, but the space would be reused on every call to that function, possibly changing the text the the pointer points at.

**NOTE WELL:** any variation on the function allocating memory to return to the caller gives the caller responsibility for *freeing* that memory when it is no longer used.  Doing so requires a pointer to the *start* of the allocated block, not to some random place in the middle, so you would need to pass back two pointers to make that work (one via an argument).

When all is said and done, I think you would be wise to choose a variation on option 1.  Were it me, I would just let the function consume the string passed to it.

**UPDATE:**
Additionally in case 2, *the program image contains the data* your pointers point to.  Supposing that it is always loaded at the same address, saving and restoring the pointer value instead of what it points to might actually work for that program only, because you reinitialize the pointed to memory by loading the program image over it.  The same does not apply if you copy the string into a working array, because even though the array has static duration, it is not initialized with the data you want to recover.

Comment: John, I tried letting the function consume the string. The trouble only shows up when the board is reset, and read from the memory for the first time. I have posted a comment/ issue on the git library page. Hoping this is my code causing the issue and not bcz of any arduino C limitation.

Comment: the point of the library is to save data to flash, so even after reset/ repowering, the data can be retrieved. Or thats how I understood it.

Comment: It is your code, but the main problem is not with function `parsePostData()`.  As @EOF already explained to you, the problem is with the way you are saving it to flash.  The fact that that seemed to work for you in case 2 is a red herring.  I have updated my answer with an explanation of why that particular special case may present an illusion of working.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. But all together it does not agree with the library's objective, and yet the library seems to work if I dont modify it. Hence I thought it was the function  :(  I will keep working on it and post any updates. thanks a lot for the detailed answer above.